# Unable to solve this limit

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

[image: Question]

$$ \underset{x\to 0}{\lim} \left(\frac{2+\cos x}{x^3\sin x}-\frac{3}{x^4}\right)$$

What I've tried so far:

$2+\cos x=1+(1+\cos x)$

$=1+\sin^2\dfrac{x}{2}$

But, I do not think this step is fruitful as I am getting stuck thereafter.
Kindly provide some sort of help or hint. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068749/neither-the-expansion-of-trigonometric-functions-nor-l-hospital-s-rule-is-allowe

Comment: Might be helpful : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: You want this solved without L'Hospital?

Comment: @Eugene Covaci yes

Answer (score 1):

Try with Taylor series.

$$\sin(x) \approx x - \frac{x^3}{6}$$

$$\cos(x) \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}$$

The result of the limit will be

$$\frac{1}{60}$$

Comment: I am not familiar with that. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Abhishekstudent Then start with unifying the fractions, and use some trick like a multiplication and a division by $x$ and so on... I'll think about another way in the meanwhile!

Comment: Sure! Let me do that.